# How to row over and partition by for a conditional logic statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data example:

```
Date    event_id    user_id  col_A  col_B   col_C
1/1/2021    a_1     1234     Bad    Green   In
1/1/2021    a_2     1234     Good   Blue    In
1/1/2021    a_3     1234     Good   Red     Out
2/7/2021    a_4     555      Good   Green   Out
2/7/2021    a_5     555      Good   Blue    None
```

Each user has multiple events that occur on the same day. Per user, I want to loop through all of their events (there is no HH:MM:SS but the day will always be the same) to check specific combinations of col_A, col_B, and col_C.

For example:

```
SELECT    
ROW_NUMBER OVER 
    (PARTITION BY user_id,event_id ORDER BY event_id ASC) AS ROW_NUM,
    user_id,
    event_id,
    date,
    col_A,
    col_B,
    col_C,
    --conditional flag
    case when col_C = "None" then "Priority 1"
    else when col_B = "Green" and col_A="Good" then "Priority 2"
    else when col_A = "Bad" then "Priority 3"
    else "Priority 4"
    end as conditional_flag

FROM sample_Table
```

The conditional flag above is what I'm trying to apply **across the partition per user_id**. I am just unsure how to apply this conditional logic to check against all row_numbers per user_id. If I apply the logic at the row_num level (as above), it seems this is only checking per row, not as an aggregate of all rows per user, with a priority such as if col_C ="None" for *any* of the rows per a user's partition then the value is set per user_id.

EDIT - adding sample query/issue screenshot below. The example of "Priority 1" is only valid at the row level for the user_id=555. My target output is for every row to reflect "Priority 1" based on checking all rows in the partition.
[image: sample_output]

Ideal output:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to assign the `row_number`  based on your conditional_flag expression? Expected results from your sample data would help.

Comment: Could you please provide the output example?

Comment: @Stu - apologies, I've updated with the output example and tested query. The results I am hoping to create is that the conditional_flag will persist across the partition per user_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want conditional counts over the whole partition:

```sql
SELECT    
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY user_id, event_id ORDER BY event_id ASC) AS ROW_NUM,
    user_id,
    event_id,
    date,
    col_A,
    col_B,
    col_C,
    --conditional flag
    case when count(case when col_C = 'None' then 1 end)
                over (partition by user_id) > 0
      then 'Priority 1'
    when count(case when col_B = 'Green' and col_A = 'Good' then 1 end)
                over (partition by user_id) > 0
      then 'Priority 2'
    when count(case when col_A = 'Bad' then 1 end)
                over (partition by user_id) > 0
      then 'Priority 3'
    else   'Priority 4'
    end as conditional_flag

FROM sample_Table;
```

Comment: I tried executing this but am still seeing Priority 1 and Priority 2 for user_id = 555. Ideally only Priority 1 would be returned for this user after checking each row in their partition.

Comment: After removing the 'event_id' from the partition and just keeping it to user_id, this returned the desired outcome.